# CSS selectors (adjacent sibling and nth-child/nth-of-type)

Tags: css

I would like to target 'Person 2' without using nth-child/nth-of-type selector however I can't seem to narrow down using adjacent sibling selectors at the moment:

https://jsfiddle.net/fk5fxbm4/4/

```
<div id="myID">
    <h2>Title</h2>

    <blockquote title="quote">
        <p>Statement 1</p>
        <cite>Person 1</cite>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
        <p>Statement 2</p>
        <cite>Person 2</cite>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
        <p>Statement 3</p>
        <cite>Person 2</cite>
    </blockquote>
</div> 

blockquote[title="quote"] cite {
    color: red;
}
```

Above code targets Person 1 however "cite + cite" or "blockquote[title="quote"] cite + cite" does not work. What am I missing here?

Also, could you explain how would I go about changing color of the last `<em>`? I have tried nth-child/nth-of-type selector however it selects multiple `<em>` each time:

https://jsfiddle.net/zs58xbch/7/

```
<main>
    <h2>Paragraph 1</h2>
    <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</em>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</em>.</p>
    <h2>Paragraph 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <em>Lorem</em> ipsum dolor sit amet.
    <h2>Paragraph 3</h2>
    <p><em>Lorem </em> ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p><em>Change my color!</em>
</main>

em:last-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please include your HTML here along with your CSS. Do not force readers to click on a link.

Comment: `p:last-of-type em { }` will change that last em.... --> https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/zs58xbch/8/

Comment: `p:last-of-type em:last-of-type {
 color: red;
}` Try this for the second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for first question**

```
blockquote[title="quote"]+blockquote cite { color: red; }
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fk5fxbm4/6/

**Answer for second question**

```
p:last-of-type em:last-of-type { color: red; }
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zs58xbch/9/

Answer (score 3):

You want to select person2 right ? Try this simple code.

**Just select adjacent `blockquote`and style the `cite`.**

```
blockquote[title="quote"] + blockquote cite{
  color: green;
}
```

**And this code use for targeting the last child.**

```
blockquote:last-child cite{
  color: cyan; //select last child
}
```

> **SNIPPET**

```css
blockquote[title="quote"] cite {
color: red;
}

blockquote[title="quote"] + blockquote cite{
  color: green; //select 2nd child
}

blockquote:last-child cite{
  color: cyan; //select last child
}
```

```html
<div id="myID">
  
          <h2>Title</h2>
          
          <blockquote title="quote">
            <p>Statement 1</p>
            <cite>Person 1</cite>
          </blockquote>
          
          <blockquote>
            <p>Statement 2</p>
            <cite>Person 2</cite>
          </blockquote>
          
          <blockquote>
            <p>Statement 3</p>
            <cite>Person 2</cite>
          </blockquote>
          
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nth selectors work within the current nesting context. So you'd need to go a level up to target the last grouping, like `blockquote:last-of-type em {}`

As for the first question, you can't target only the second of something without nth selectors. I suggest adding a class.

[edit] okay you *can* hack together an nth-child(2) approximation as Andrei commented on this answer. I still recommend using a class though.

Comment: *You can't target the second of something without nth selectors*. Really? How about `.parent>*:first-child + * {}` ?

Comment: My bad - was mentally scrambling that and the general sibling selector. That specifically would work, but not very scalable for beyond 2nd.

Comment: I never said it's scalable. It actually feels like scratching on the right side with the left hand. But you said it wasn't possible and I found that not exactly accurate. Cheers!